# Calling an objects method in the MAIN.py from another object who has a different scope in Python

Tags: python, object, methods, scope

In Python.. 
I have a Main.py that has 3 tableview variables x,y, and z.
My myguiQtwindow.py has a Gui has 3 buttons, button1, button2, and button3.

I am trying to make it so that my GUI object can call the instantiated object in main when someone clicks  button...

```
#MAIN.py
class mytedious_Table(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
    more stuff

x=mytedious
y=mytedious
z=mytedious

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = main()

# do stuff here

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


#myguiQtwindow.py

Class Ui_MainWindow

    ...
    ...
    ...
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_LoadCSVFile, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.choosefile)

def choose_file(self):
     global x.loadfile()
```

It is this LAST call I'm trying to do to main, that has me baffled.  Should be able to do it I'm thinking its easy qualifier I'm missing.  I'm new to Python... Forgive all the pseudo code here... Hopefully someone knows what I'm asking.

Comment: At first: all the code after `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is not going to be called. So I hope it belongs to a ode block and you just formatted it badly.

Comment: Yes the comment before that is suppose to denote that code after the sys.exit is in another file...